# Unable to get actual Markup from a page with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, selenium, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape this URL with combination of `BeautifulSoup` and `Selinium`

```
http://starwood.ugc.bazaarvoice.com/3523si-en_us/115/reviews.djs?format=embeddedhtml&page=2&scrollToTop=true
```

I have tried this code

```
active_review_page_html  = browser.page_source
active_review_page_html = active_review_page_html.replace('\\', "")
hotel_page_soup = BeautifulSoup(active_review_page_html)
print(hotel_page_soup)
```

But what is does that it is returning me data like

```
;&lt;span class="BVRRReviewText"&gt;Hotel accommodations and staff were fine ....
```

But I have to scrape that span from that page with

```
for review_div in hotel_page_soup.select("span .BVRRReviewText"):
```

How can I get real markup from that URL?

Comment: active_review_page_html this is your markup!

Comment: But that is also like `;&lt;span class="BVRRReviewText"`

If you visit the URL it is not like the output I am getting by Selinium

Comment: Or should I replace `&lt;` with `<` and the other too????? so it makes `<span class="BVRRReviewText"`

Comment: where does this active_review_page_html  come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are giving us the wrong link, instead of the [actual page](http://www.starwoodhotels.com/sheraton/property/reviews/index.html?propertyID=115&language=en_US) you are trying to scrape, you give us a link to the participating in the page load js file which would be a unnecessary challenge to parse.

Secondly, you don't need `BeautifulSoup` in this case, `selenium` itself is good at locating elements and extracting the text or attributes. No need for an extra step here.

Here's a working example using the actual page with reviews you want to get:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # or webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.starwoodhotels.com/sheraton/property/reviews/index.html?propertyID=115&language=en_US')

# wait for the reviews to load
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.BVRRReviewText")))

# get reviews
for review_div in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span.BVRRReviewText"):
    print(review_div.text)
    print("---")

driver.close()
```

Prints:

```
This is not a low budget hotel . Yet the hotel offers no amenities. Nothing and no WiFi. In fact, you block the wifi that comes with my celluar plan. I am a part of 2 groups that are loyal to the Sheraton, Alabama A&M and the 9th Episcopal District AMEChurch but the Sheraton is not loyal to us.
---
We are a company that had (5) guest rooms at the hotel. Despite having a credit card on file for room and tax charges, my guest was charged the entire amount to her personal credit card. It has taken me (5) PHONE CALLS and my own time and energy to get this bill reversed. I guess leaving a message with information and a phone number numerous times is IGNORED at this hotel. You can guarantee that we will not return with our business. YOu may thank Kimerlin or Kimberly in your accounting office for her lack of personal service and follow through for the lost business in the future.
---
...
```

<sup>I've intentionally left you to handle pagination - let me know if you have difficulties.</sup>

Comment: Dear how can I navigate through review pages as you can see that if you click on 2nd page, its URL does not changes ... while if you see the JS link in 2nd page .. that is what I have to crawl ... I currently I am navigating through pages by scraping the `a`s `href` values of Pagination div

Comment: @Mani this is what I've left for you to implement. Please make a separate question out of it explaining what difficulties do you currently have. Thanks.

Comment: Hey I can scrape pages with Selinum but I do not want to use it ... please see my question